# Include openssl in app

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I am trying to build a standalone version of Bitmessage for OS X. So far, I have managed to include PyQt4 in the build by having the following setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['bitmessagemain.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True,
 'iconfile': '/Users/jackson/Desktop/Bitmessagelogo-reduced.icns', 'includes': ['PyQt4']}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

I can't seem to figure out how to bundle openssl in my includes. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Py2app should detect a dependency on openssl if there is an import statement for an extension that links with openssl (for example the stdlib SSL support or pyOpenSSL).

That said, py2app will not include the copy of openssl from /usr/lib into your application bundle. Files from system locations (such as /usr/lib and /System) are assumed to be operating system files and are never included in bundles created by py2app.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to include it in the bundle?

Comment: It is not possible to force py2app to include files from /usr/lib, and that is intentional.

Comment: :( So there is no way for this to be a standalone app?

Comment: Sure there is: don't link to openssl in /usr/lib, but use a separate copy (for example from HomeBrew). You'll have to rebuild the python extensions that use openssl.

Comment: BTW. Two reasons for not including files from /usr/lib into application bundles: 1) licensing worries, 2) libraries might not work on other OSX releases anyway (as an example, Apple's openssl build is patched and uses private APIs for some functionality, there is no reason to assume that these private APIs are stable acros OSX releases)

Comment: @RonaldOussoren how would i go about adding the openssl binaries installed through brew to the bundle? do I have to supply some kwarg to the `setup` call or add it to `OPTIONS` dict maybe?