# py2app, pycrypto, aes not found

Tags: python, openssl, aes, py2app

It's the first time I'm using py2app.
I've manage to make a bundle(?)/app from my python scripts, but as said in this topics [Include openssl in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015490/include-openssl-in-app) openssl is not include in my app, but i don't understand if pycrypto can not be included also or if i'm doing wrong.
So when I try to execute my app, i got an ImportError telling me that aes was not found.

```
main[15198]:   File "/Users/lumy-meludia/Meludia/clients/campaign_manager_gui/dist/main.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 351, in <module>
main[15198]:     _run()
main[15198]:   File "/Users/lumy-meludia/Meludia/clients/campaign_manager_gui/dist/main.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 336, in _run
main[15198]:     exec(compile(source, path, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
main[15198]:   File "/Users/lumy-meludia/Meludia/clients/campaign_manager_gui/dist/main.app/Contents/Resources/main.py", line 16, in <module>
main[15198]:     from campaign_manager_gui.client_campaign.CampaignClient import run
main[15198]:   File "campaign_manager_gui/client_campaign/CampaignClient.pyc", line 21, in <module>
main[15198]:   File "pymelu_client/client/ClientNetwork.pyc", line 13, in <module>
main[15198]:   File "OpenSSL/__init__.pyc", line 8, in <module>
main[15198]:   File "OpenSSL/rand.pyc", line 11, in <module>
main[15198]:   File "OpenSSL/_util.pyc", line 4, in <module>
main[15198]:   File "cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.pyc", line 89, in __init__
main[15198]:   File "cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.pyc", line 113, in _ensure_ffi_initialized
main[15198]:   File "cryptography/hazmat/bindings/utils.pyc", line 47, in build_ffi
main[15198]: ImportError: No module named aes
```

i've tried to add pycrypto to the include in my setup file

```
APP = ["campaign_manager_gui/gui/main.py"]
DATA_FILES = ['campaign_manager_gui/gui', 'campaign_manager_gui/client_campaign',]
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True, 'includes': ['pycrypto']}
setup(
  app=APP,
  data_files=DATA_FILES,
  options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
  setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

but the result of `py setup.py py2app` give me

```
running py2app
creating /Users/lumy-meludia/Meludia/clients/campaign_manager_gui/build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app
creating /Users/lumy-meludia/Meludia/clients/campaign_manager_gui/build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app/collect
creating /Users/lumy-meludia/Meludia/clients/campaign_manager_gui/build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app/temp
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app/lib-dynload
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app/Frameworks
/Users/lumy-meludia/.pyenv/versions/env_2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/modulegraph/find_modules.py:258: UserWarning: No module named pycrypto
  warn("No module named %s"%(mod,))
*** using recipe: virtualenv ***
*** using recipe: ftplib ***
*** using recipe: lxml ***
*** using recipe: xml ***
*** using recipe: sip ***
*** using recipe: pydoc ***
*** using recipe: ctypes ***
*** filtering dependencies ***
1191 total
46 filtered
115 orphaned
1145 remaining
*** create binaries ***
[...]
```

Could you help me to include pycrypto and Openssl in my app?

Comment: No i couldn't, I've found some road for this, like recompile yourself openssl and other dependencies, but that was not possible for my situation (on a mac, and not an expert mac, so recompile with all dependencies, using xcode wasn't an option.
Should I add my edit as an answer or it's just a tips for the next time ?

Answer (score 1):

After few days of looking, I've found a post on stackoverflow where they explain that py2app will not take libraries that come either from /usr/lib  or /System
[Include openssl in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015490/include-openssl-in-app) there is logical reason to that.

So they propose to recompile yourself OpenSSL and other dependencies and as I'm on a mac, and not an expert of XCode and mac, i decided this was not a **fast** solution for me.

After other look I've found pyinstaller https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki which does the same as py2app but with less trouble.

You just have to be sure that all your package are installed on your system (or virtualenv) and it's works well.

Answer (score 0):

You may try fixing the problem with

```
pip install slowaes
```

Comment: What does it do? How does it help with the problem? You could improve your answer by adding information or reference.